# Users require "Customize Application" system permission to edit/create object

Tags: custom-object, profile

- Users  require "Customize Application" system permission to
  edit/create object
- Profile has Modify all permission on that object

Has anyone see this before? Just toggling the customize application permission alone is enough to enable/disable their access to edit/create this object.

Comment: What is the type of the object? Is it a custom setting or a standard sObject?

Comment: It is a sObject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was a previous admin had added a field linking to an in development custom object to the page. Removing this field fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Following permissions are enabled automatically when the Customize Application profile permission is enabled.

**[Customize Application (Permission)](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000194001):**

> Customize the organization using App Setup menu options.
>
> Edit messages and custom links;
>
> Modify standard picklist values;
>
> Create, edit, and delete custom fields;
>
> Create, edit, and delete page layouts (also requires the “Edit”
>   permission for the object, for example, “Edit” on accounts);
>
> Set field-level security;
>
> Create, edit, and delete custom links;
>
> Edit the Lead Settings;
>
> Activate big deal alerts;
>
> Create record types;
>
> Set up Web-to-Case and email response rules;
>
> Set up Web-to-Lead and email response rules;
>
> Set up assignment and escalation rules;
>
> Set up business hours;
>
> Set up Email-to-Case or On-Demand Email-to-Case;
>
> Edit Self-Service page layouts and portal color theme (also requires
>   the “Manage Self-Service Portal” permission to set up and maintain
>   Self-Service settings and delete your organization's Self-Closed Case
>   Status value);
>
> Set up and enable multilingual solutions;
>
> Set up team selling;
>
> Set up account teams;
>
> Map custom lead fields;
>
> Manage queues;
>
> Create, edit, and delete workflow rules, tasks, field updates,
>   outbound messages, and alerts;
>
> **Create, edit, and delete custom s-controls, custom objects, and custom
>   tabs;**
>
> Rename tabs;
>
> Manage custom apps and Service Cloud console apps;
>
> Create and edit public calendars and resources;
>
> Set up the console;
>
> Enable, set up, and modify the Salesforce Customer Portal;
>
> Set up and schedule analytic snapshots to run;
>
> Create communities for ideas and answers;
>
> Create Visualforce email templates

Comment: There are no s controls on the edit/new page. The buttons haven't been redirected. The profile has modify all access to the object.  Really it seems any profile lacking the customize application can't get to edit/create this object.

Comment: There are triggers on the object but they are after triggers - users cannot even open the edit/new screens :(

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to use Force.com license with a Standard CRM object that it shouldn't have access.

Answer (score -1):

You can clone a standard user profile but if you choose a "salesforce platform" license you will not be able to find the "customize application" permission.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [answer]. Right now, I don't think this answers the question being asked. This site thrives on details. While it is possible to include too much detail, doing that is a lot harder than not providing enough detail.